# PowerBI Report Server says "Sorry you do not have access to this folder. Please choose a different folder and try again"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, powerbi, reportserver

I am new to powerBI. I was trying to work with PowerBI Report Server.

[image: PowerBI Desktop Report Server]

`http://servername/Reports/` (as shown in the screenshot is my report server address). When I try to save my report to a report server. I get this error.

It error says "I do not have access to this folder".

I am not sure what folder is talked about here. I don't find any folder called "reports". Can someone tell me where I can look for this folder.

Or is something wrong with my report server configuration?

I guess it's got to do with my database configuration in process of report server management configuration.

During the configuration of Database in report server. If I have the database credential as `NTAuthority/NetworkService` I get this error[shown in the 1st screenshot]. And in the browser I get this error:

[image]

I created user in SQL Server and I have access to the user account. When I change the credentials to that user account(in the report server configuration)  and open the URL I get this error on the browser:

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVkt1.png]

Comment: It looks like the ReportServer may be installed on a local machine for development purposes? If this is the first time you have installed and configured an SSRS server you may have overlooked setting up permissions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/granting-permissions-on-a-native-mode-report-server

Comment: Hold on! This question is tagged as [tag:Ssrs-2012]. Is that really the version of SSRS that you have installed?

Comment: No this is powerBI report server. It was similar to SSRS. Thought someone might help.

Comment: I think the process described in that link might still be valid.